# Drop a premise in a goal in apply style

Tags: isabelle

let's assume I want to show the following lemma

```
lemma "⟦ A; B; C ⟧ ⟹ D"
```

I get the goal

```
1. A ⟹ B ⟹ C ⟹ D
```

However, I don't need `B`. How can I transfer my goal to something like

```
1. A ⟹ C ⟹ D
```

I don't want to alter the original `lemma` statement, just the current goal in apply style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is `apply (thin_tac B)`. However, the last time I did this, Peter Lammich shouted "Oh god, why are you doing this!" in disgust and rewrote my proof in order to get rid of the thin_tac. So using this tactic doesn't exactly seem to be encouraged anymore.

Comment: Here is a realistic example that shows what happens when you use `thin_tac` all the time: http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Group-Ring-Module.shtml

Comment: Note that you can also use a pattern inside `thin_tac`: for example, `apply (thin_tac "?x ∧ ?y")` would discard the premise `(1 + 1 = 2) ∧ (2 + 2 = 4)`. This can help reduce that amount of typing/duplication in your proof scripts.

Answer (score 5):

Normally it is better to avoid unwanted stuff in a goal state, instead of removing it later.  The way you formulate a proof problem affects the way you solve it.

This is particularly important for structured proofs: you appeal *positively* to those facts that should participate in the next step of the proof, instead of suppressing some of them *negatively*.

E.g. like this:

```
from `A` and `C` have D ...
```

Telling which facts are relevant to a proof is already a start for readability.

Following that style, your initial problem will look like this:

```
lemma
  assumes A and B and C 
  shows D
proof -
  from `A` and `C` show D sorry
qed
```

or like this with reduced verbosity, if A B C D are large propositions:

```
lemma
  assumes a: A and b: B and c: C 
  shows D
proof -
  from a c show ?thesis sorry
qed
```

Comment: Can such "positive appealing" be done in an apply-style script? Initial assumptions can of course be named, but what about intermediate assumptions?

Comment: If you insist in one big apply script to make a proof, it is getting difficult.  But why do this?  You can easily make the outer structure in proper Isar, and degrade towards apply scripts only in leaf positions, if at all.