# Drop a variable in a goal in apply style

Tags: isabelle

Having recently learnt [how to drop an unwanted premise in an apply-style proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311959/drop-a-premise-in-a-goal-in-apply-style), I now wonder how to drop an unneeded *variable*. That is, suppose I have the goal

```
1. !!x y z. A ⟹ B ⟹ C
```

where `y` does not appear in `A`, `B` or `C`. How can I transform it to the following?

```
1. !!x z. A ⟹ B ⟹ C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`triv_forall_equality` is indeed the Pure rule to strip redundant parameters.  There is also `prune_params_tac` to do that as ML tactic, it operates on all subgoals.  Note that the latter is not exposed as Isar proof method, since it is hardly ever required in practice: tools like `simp` and `auto` already include it by default.

Note that the approach via `(simp only: triv_forall_equality)` works in many situations, but there is also a snag: the `only` modifier in Isabelle/HOL does a bit more than "only" using the given simp rules.  It includes things like arithmetic solvers, which might cause surprise or confusion some situations.

To imitate `prune_params_tac` precisely within the Isar method language, you could use `(unfold triv_forall_equality)` although there is a tiny conceptual snag: its use of arbitrary rewriting instead of just infolding equations `c = t` is just a historical accident.

Answer (score 2):

A simple:

```
apply simp
```

will do the trick. If you don't want to perform any other transformations on the goal state, you can try:

```
apply (simp only: triv_forall_equality)
```

which will remove the unnecessary meta-quantifiers, but otherwise not modify the goal state.